# Make Struts2 form use setId(Long) instead of setId(String)

Tags: java, struts2, struts

First, I have a form, that's for editing a persisted dataset. 
I have a hidden field, that holds the id of the dataset, to be edited. When i submit the form, I get a `NoSucheMethodException`, because Struts wants to have a method `setId(String)`, but my bean only has a `setId(long)`.

I don't really want to create another method, to convert from String to long. Is there any way, to make Struts parse this value to long, on its own?

Comment: Ok, I found my fault. Had to put the form attributes into a <s:push value="beanName">. Now it works just as I wanted it.

Comment: Please close or self answer the question so we can see it resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to surround the form with `<s:push value="nameOfYourBean">`, to make Struts act as I wanted it. Sorry for the unnecessary question...